# How to change SKScene position before presenting?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene, iphone-xs-max

I am trying to adjust `SKScene` position based on the device the game is running. For example due to 'top notch' area of iPhone XS Max, I need to subtract that height from `SKScene` height and position the scene accordingly.

So here is how I calculate the height aka `safeAreaHeight` in the `AppDelegate` and subtract from scene height aka `sceneHeight`:

```
    safeAreaHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
    sceneHeight -= safeAreaHeight
```

In `GameViewController` I try to re-position the SKScene like below:

```
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'MainMenuScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainMenuScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
            scene.size.height = sceneHeight
            scene.size.width = sceneWidth
            scene.position.y -= safeAreaHeight
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
```

However, I am getting below error:

> SKScene: Setting the position of a SKScene has no effect.

Additionally, I tried to use `SKAction` to move position of the `SKScene` as well, then I received below error:

> SKScene: Animating the position of a SKScene has no effect.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I size the scene to the view controller's view and position nodes to avoid notches (or potentially other non-safe areas) as necessary. Is there a reason this wouldn't work for your situation? If you adjust the scene for the safe area, what are you expecting to display next to the notch? I kinda like that the sky, or other background, fills that space.

Comment: @JKaz I didn't try to size to view controller's view. Is the view controller's view equals to 'safe area'? I just want that area to be plain black color. I am not going to utilize that area.

Comment: The vc's view is the screen, not just the safe area. The safe area insets are a property of the view. Where I've seen or worked with skScene, the scene fills the screen and individual controls/nodes/etc are positioned within the safe area, avoiding a non-safe area that looks different from the safe area. I think it's recommended to not separately color the non-safe areas, though in a quick look, I didn't find a source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured how to achieve this, I am sharing in case it would help someone else.

Inside `AppDelegate` you get the correct safe area values and store it in a singleton (in my case: `safeAreaHeight`) for access throughout the app. Subtract the amount from scene height (`sceneHeight`).

```
    let kWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows[0]
    safeAreaHeight = kWindow.safeAreaInsets.top + kWindow.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    screenHeight = screenRect.size.height - safeAreaHeight
```

Don't forget the adjust the `sceneHeight` in GameViewController before presenting it:

```
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'MainMenuScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MainMenuScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
            scene.size.height = sceneHeight
            scene.size.width = sceneWidth
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
```

Inside loaded scene, in this case it is `MainMenuScene`, you simply find subview of SKScene and adjust its Y position by subtracting the `safeAreaHeight` at its center

```
    guard let subView = self.view else { return }
    subView.center.y -= safeAreaHeight
```

PS.: Do not adjust all the views in different scenes (ie.: GameScene, GameOverScene etc.) Once you adjust, it remains throughout the app.